# Select everything from one table, and certain columns from another SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

How can I select everything from one table and certain columns from another when creating a view,

For example I've wrote

```
CREATE VIEW NOT_IN_MAN_GLA_LND
AS 
     SELECT 
         E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, 
         E.HOUSE_NO, E.ADDRESS, E.POSTCODE, E.TELE_NO, E.START_DATE, 
         P.CITY, P.POST_CODE
     FROM 
         EMPLOYEE E, POSTCODE P
     WHERE 
         E.POSTCODE = P.POSTCODE
         AND P.CITY NOT IN ('MAN', 'GLA', 'LND');
```

So instead of writing all the column from the employee table is there anyway I can just select them all while still selecting only the two from the postcode table.

Comment: You can use `SELECT *`, but I would consider it a bad practice in any serious code. What happens if someone adds a column to your table? Surprise, it's not in your view! Just type out the columns. It will take you 60 seconds and you're done. SQL Developer will even do it for you.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace VIEW NOT_IN_MAN_GLA_LND
AS SELECT E.*, P.CITY, P.POST_CODE as P_POST_CODE

FROM EMPLOYEE E, POSTCODE P

WHERE E.POSTCODE = P.POSTCODE

AND P.CITY NOT IN ('MAN', 'GLA', 'LND');

for example dept nd emp table:

create or replace view ns_1_v as
select e.*,d.deptno as d_dname,d.dname 
from scott.emp e ,scott.dept d
where
e.deptno=d.deptno;
```

you have to give aliases for the column names where there is a common name in  both the tables otherwise it will throw`dupllicaate column name error` in your case `postcode` is common so give alias for it

Answer (score 2):

The better answer is to use proper, explicit, **STANDARD** `JOIN` syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW NOT_IN_MAN_GLA_LND AS
    SELECT E.*, P.CITY, P.POST_CODE
    FROM EMPLOYEE E JOIN
         POSTCODE P
         ON E.POSTCODE = P.POSTCODE
    WHERE P.CITY NOT IN ('MAN', 'GLA', 'LND');
```

If you wanted to include employees in the results -- even those who have no matching postal code -- then:

```
CREATE VIEW NOT_IN_MAN_GLA_LND AS
    SELECT E.*, P.CITY, P.POST_CODE
    FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN
         POSTCODE P
         ON E.POSTCODE = P.POSTCODE
    WHERE P.CITY NOT IN ('MAN', 'GLA', 'LND') OR
          P.CITY IS NULL;
```